# I am trying to read from a .csv file with fscanf

Tags: c

I am trying to read from a csv file but the output is not what I expected 
Output is this:

```
|1| |Dummy,Person| || 
|2| |Dummy,Person| || 
|3| |Dummy,Person| || 
|4| |Dummy,Person| ||
```

I want it to be:

```
|1| |Dummy| |Person| 
|2| |Dummy| |Person| 
|3| |Dummy| |Person| 
|4| |Dummy| |Person|
```

What should I do?  Here is the code:

```
struct Person {
    int id;
    char firstname[50];
    char lastname[50];
} Person;

void loadPersonInfo(FILE *fp) {
    int knt;
    int id;

    for (knt = 1; knt < 5; knt++) {
        struct Person new_person;
        char firstname[50];
        char lastname[50];

        fscanf(fp, "%d , %s ,%s ", &id, firstname, lastname);

        strcpy(new_person.firstname, firstname);
        strcpy(new_person.lastname, lastname);
        new_person.id = id;
        People[knt] = new_person;
        printf("|%d| |%s| |%s| \n", People[knt].id, People[knt].firstname,
               People[knt].lastname);
    }
}

void readFile() {
    printf("Reading Data From People.csv File.\r\n ");
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("People.csv", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened \r\n");
    } else {
        loadPersonInfo(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Done!\r\n");
}
```

Comment: do you mean that the `struct` field are assigned in the wrong order?

Comment: I know nothing of fscanf, but the spacing in `"%d , %s ,%s "` looks suspicious to me without an example line from the CSV file.

Comment: Because `%s` is not stopping on `,`, it's stopping on first non-whitespace character. A `%[^,]` would stop on `,`. Check the return value from `fscanf`.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman It should output like i mentioned in the question but it is taking firstname and lastname together with a comma between. I did not understand why i did not get the output that i want. By the way i am new to c language.

Answer (score 1):

Because `%s` is not stopping on `,`. It is stopping on first non-whitespace character. So first `%s` in your scanf reads the line up until the newline character, including the `,` and second field.

A `%[^,]` would stop on first `,`. Make sure to check the return value from `fscanf`. Don't use `%s` or `%[` without specifying maximum width, so that you protect against overflow errors.

```
int ret = fscanf(fp, "%d,%49[^,],%49[^\n]", &id, firstname, lastname);
if (ret != 3) { 
      // AAaaa! error
      abort();
}
```

[cppreference scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

> for (knt = 1; knt < 5; knt++)

Note that arrays are indexed from 0, not from 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try that and get back to you.

Comment: The second `%49[^,]` will consume the rest of the line, and the newline and the id of the next record. The format should be `"%d,%49[^,],%49[^\n]%*1[\n]"`. Also hint that empty fields will cause conversion failures... `fscanf()` is a quick a dirty solution for this job, with many quirks and limitations. Error recovery is very limited too.